# i got error Failed to validate the certificate chain, error: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException

Tags: android

all I got the below error

Failed to validate the certificate chain, error: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.

I try Different Solution but still get the Same Is there any updation to Ignore SSL Certificate.

I tried Below Code

```
wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {
            switch (error.getPrimaryError()) {
                case SslError.SSL_UNTRUSTED:
                    Log.d(TAG, "onReceivedSslError: The certificate authority is not trusted.");
                    break;
                case SslError.SSL_EXPIRED:
                    Log.d(TAG, "onReceivedSslError: The certificate has expired.");
                    break;
                case SslError.SSL_IDMISMATCH:
                    Log.d(TAG, "onReceivedSslError: The certificate Hostname mismatch.");
                    break;
                case SslError.SSL_NOTYETVALID:
                    Log.d(TAG, "onReceivedSslError: The certificate is not yet valid.");
                    break;
            }
            handler.proceed();
        }
    });
```

Comment: It's not recommended to ignore SSL Cert, But since you want to ignore it. Just remove switch block and keep only `handler.proceed();` it should work.

Comment: i tried but its not working

Comment: not working as in ? Are you getting any error?

Comment: not error but it just info, but the page is not showing in webview and onpagefinish() is called perfactly.

Comment: Just remove switch block and keep only `handler.proceed();` and  add `return;` try this